# Trouble parsing some names out of a chunk of xml elements

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I've written a script in python in combination with BeautifulSoup to parse some names out of some `xml` elements but for some reason the script throws attribute error just before the print statement. How can I make it work? Thanks in advance.

What I've tried so far:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

content="""
 <ns:Car>
  <ns:Model>sedan</ns:Model>
  <ns:Model>coupe</ns:Model>
  <ns:Model>hatchback</ns:Model>
  <ns:Model>convertible</ns:Model>
 </ns:Car>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(content,"xml")
for items in soup.find("ns:Car").find_all("ns:Model"):
    print(items)
```

Expected output:

```
sedan
coupe
hatchback
convertible
```

The error it throws:

```
    for items in soup.find("ns:Car").find_all("ns:Model"):
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'
```

Btw, I'm not willing to comply with any solution related to `regular expression`. I like parse the same using `BeautifulSoup`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your call to `soup.find("ns:Car")` is returning an object of type `NoneType` and you are trying to call the `find_all` method of this `NoneType` object. Try changing the last couple of lines to:

```
for items in soup.find("Car").find_all("Model"):
    print(items)
```